# R Shiny - Multiple valueBoxes in 1 row

Tags: r, shiny

I am fairly new to R Shiny and I would like to create 1 row with 8 valueBoxes. I used the code below but it is not showing all boxes on the same row. I tried setting the width to 1.5 (given the Bootstrap width of 12, divided over 8 boxes), but it doesn't seem to accept decimal values. Any ideas?

```
  fluidRow( 
    valueBoxOutput("box1"),
    valueBoxOutput("box2"),
    valueBoxOutput("box3"),
    valueBoxOutput("box4"),
    valueBoxOutput("box5"),
    valueBoxOutput("box6"),
    valueBoxOutput("box7"),
    valueBoxOutput("box8")
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `splitLayout`:

```
library(shinydashboard)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    splitLayout(
      valueBoxOutput("box1"),
      valueBoxOutput("box2"),
      valueBoxOutput("box3"),
      valueBoxOutput("box4"),
      valueBoxOutput("box5"),
      valueBoxOutput("box6"),
      valueBoxOutput("box7"),
      valueBoxOutput("box8")
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output){
    output$box1 <- renderInfoBox({
      infoBox(
        "box1",
        "A",
        icon = icon("credit-card")
      )
    })
    output$box2 <- renderInfoBox({
      infoBox(
        "box2",
        "B",
        icon = icon("credit-card")
      )
    })
    output$box3 <- renderInfoBox({
      infoBox(
        "box3",
        "C",
        icon = icon("credit-card")
      )
    })
    output$box4 <- renderInfoBox({
      infoBox(
        "box4",
        "D",
        icon = icon("credit-card")
      )
    })
    output$box5 <- renderInfoBox({
      infoBox(
        "box5",
        "E",
        icon = icon("credit-card")
      )
    })
    output$box6 <- renderInfoBox({
      infoBox(
        "box6",
        "F",
        icon = icon("credit-card")
      )
    })
    output$box7 <- renderInfoBox({
      infoBox(
        "box7",
        "G",
        icon = icon("credit-card")
      )
    })
    output$box8 <- renderInfoBox({
      infoBox(
        "box8",
        "H",
        icon = icon("credit-card")
      )
    })
  }
)
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your comment. However, when I use this method, for some reason the background color of the valueBox doesn't spread over the entire box. Here's a screenshot to clarify: https://imgur.com/a/WEUZUvu

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of shiny's grid layout by placing each object in a separate column. Try:

```
 fluidRow( 
    column(1, valueBoxOutput("box1")),
    column(1, valueBoxOutput("box2")),
    column(1, valueBoxOutput("box3")),
    column(1, valueBoxOutput("box4")),
    column(1, valueBoxOutput("box5")),
    column(1, valueBoxOutput("box6")),
    column(1, valueBoxOutput("box7")),
    column(1, valueBoxOutput("box8"))
  )
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. However, when I do this the boxes are not spread across the whole width of the row (which is 12). Any ideas?

Comment: For anyone else coming across this. You need to add width=NULL for column-based layouts: i.e. valueBoxOutput("box1", width=NULL)

Comment: @vdvaxel Hi, can I kindly ask if you manage to resolve this?

Comment: @AdamWaring please write this as an answer. it did help!